# Duplicate Rules: "The XXX field is invalid for this field mapping" - during deployment

Tags: deployment, duplicate-management

During a deploy from source control to an org, I get this error:

```
Contact.Standard_Rule_for_Contacts_with_Duplicate_Leads
Duplicate Rule The Phone field is invalid for this field mapping.
```

What would the reasons be for this to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How I got into this state is another story ...*

Here's why this can happen:

> Your source control is out of sync with the deployment target org.

The specific reason in our org was:

- Source control was populated from PROD. This included the default duplicate rule `Contact.Standard_Rule_for_Contacts_with_Duplicate_Leads`.
- This default duplicate rule includes mapping of the OOTB `Phone` field on Contact.
- Shield Platform deterministic encryption was (much later in time) enabled for the `Contact.Phone` field and deployed to PROD
- Duplicate rules [don't support probabilistic encryption fields in the Field Mapping](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_matching_rules.htm&type=5). SFDC auto-disables these mappings upon detecting a probabilistically-encrypted field.
- No one realized this (because the rule had never been activated) so source control's copy of the duplicate rule was never updated.
- A subsequent deploy (e.g. a CI job) from source control of that duplicate rule to any Org that originated from PROD fails with the error `The Phone field is invalid for this field mapping`